# How to extract individual values from output aws cli --query

Tags: zsh, aws-cli

I'm running this query with `zsh`:

```
output=$(aws sagemaker describe-training-job \
    --training-job-name $name \
    --query '{S3ModelArtifacts:ModelArtifacts.S3ModelArtifacts,TrainingImage:AlgorithmSpecification.TrainingImage,RoleArn:RoleArn}')
```

But for the life of me I can't seem to individually extract out `S3ModelArtifacts`, `TrainingImage`, and `RoleArn`.

It seems to be neither an array nor an associative array?  But it looks like it's json format when I do `echo $output`.

Ultimately I just want to be able to do something like `var=${output[TrainingImage]}` but this just gives me the whole response instead of just the TrainingImage value.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command line tool [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse json output like so:

```
(19-11-27 10:25:38) <0> [~] printf %s "$output" | jq '.TrainingImage'
"123456789877.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/kmeans:1"
```

Or, as this is a pretty simple query, you can use [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

```
(19-11-27 10:25:43) <0> [~] printf %s "$output" | sed -n -e 's/^.*TrainingImage"://p'
 "123456789877.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/kmeans:1",
```

Here is the [explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24140/return-only-the-portion-of-a-line-after-a-matching-pattern) of the sed command.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want extra installations so I was trying to use your sed example but it leaves a trailing comma at the end.  I tried reviewing the sed docs but I'm starting with no sed knowledge and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Try this command:

`printf %s "$output" | sed -n -e 's/^.*\TrainingImage": \(".*"\).*$/\1/p'`

Essentially it is matching the 1st (`\1`) regex group in the expression. If you wanted the value without the quotes you could do the following:

`printf %s "$output" | sed -n -e 's/^.*\TrainingImage": "\(.*\)".*$/\1/p'`